# Letters in label messed up of flot grapn

Tags: jquery-plugins, flot

I am using flot to display a bar graph. Due to the long label of x-axis, I use a js plug-in which named jquery.flot.tickrotor.js. 
The label looks fine on most computers. But on some computers, the letters in the label are kind of messed up and the font looks strange.
I really want to post the pic to show the display but I don't have enough reputation to do so.
Does anyone know what may cause this problem?

Comment: You mentioned in a comment to my original answer that you're only using Chrome.  Can you provide any more such information?  What operating systems and versions are you using?  Which show the problem and which don't?  Does your text contain non-ASCII characters?

Comment: So far, we have 10 computers and only 1 show the problem.The one has problem is using windows 7 and all other computers using ubuntu 11.10 have no problem. My test didn't contain non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels are probably rotated using CSS transforms.  Some browsers - mainly IE 7 & 8 - do a poor job of rendering the rotated labels.

If the plugin supports rendering text to canvas directly, enabling that should fix the problem.  Otherwise there's nothing you can do about it.  Since those browsers are disappearing from the market due to their age, the problem will eventually just disappear.

Comment: But all the computers use the same browser-Chrome to view the page, why some are ok while others not?